# Update Table Column value in BigQuery using BigQueryClient

Tags: google-bigquery

I am uploading my data on a daily basis into BigQuery tables from C# application using BigQueryClient UploadJson Method. Some of the values from the table columns get updated on a frequent basis, and those updates need to be applied on BigQuery too.

It seems BigQuery won't allow updating those values from my C# application. Is it possible to update the table using the BigQuery client library?
Insert Example :

```
  using (BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(_projectId, _googleCredential))
            {
                BigQueryTable table = client.GetTable(_datasetId, _tableId);
                BigQueryJob job = table.UploadJson(dataStream, new UploadJsonOptions() { AllowUnknownFields = true });
                return CheckJobStatus(client, job.Reference);
            }
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking. Do you need to update rows in the table? Or add/remove columns?

Comment: I need to update the  columns value. I have corrected my question now .

Comment: Do you want to add/remove columns, or update the rows/values?!

Comment: I want to update value of few columns of the particular row

Comment: Then DML. But, note: there are limits: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax

Comment: I have gone through this link but i have to achieve it using BigQueryClient from C# application , I am also inserting rows into BigQuery Table using BigQueryClient  UploadJson method.

Comment: Just to add up to the use of DML, check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language) to know how to enable its use on BigQuery. Could you please provide an example on how do you proceed with the inserts in BigQuery using C#? Are you preparing your program like [this] (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries)

Comment: Hello Rodrigo, Yes I am using BigQueryClient to insert . I have added insert example in the question

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but based on your description, you are using JSON to upload your changes. By looking at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#appending_to_or_overwriting_a_table_with_json_data), there are various options for doing so, but if you want to do it programatically, it is only possible using Python or Ruby.

Comment: The documents provide options to append the data not updating rows values

Comment: I think DML is the way to go then. @GrahamPolley, could you please elaborate on this and post an answer explaining how to use it correctly? Thanks.